# Java is not responding while opening Eclipse in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 18.04 (64bit)
And I have installed `java oracle 1.8` and `eclipse 4.7.0 M3`.
Ubuntu says java is not responding while opening eclipse.

I have attached screenshot with this.
[image]

Comment: There could be several issues, CPU is busy, no free memory, excessive IO etc.

Comment: Indeed quite hard to debug. Try rebooting, reinstalling, check your htop for memory usage etc.

Comment: Eclise 4.7.0 M3 was a pre-release Milestone release of Eclipse 4.7, this is not something that you should be installing now. The current release of Eclipse is 4.7.3a (Oxygen.3a).

Comment: I'm having the same trouble: The message disappears after eclipse is loaded. But it is really annoying when in debug mode. Prevents me from working with the debugger!